# What is the solution, $f(n)$, of the following functional equation: $mf(m)+nf(n)=(m+n+xmn)f(m+n+xmn)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, functional-equations

What is the solution, $f(n)$, of the following functional equation:

$$mf(m)+nf(n)=(m+n+xmn)f(m+n+xmn) ,$$

where $f$ takes on integer values, $m$ and $n$ are integers, and $x$ is an indeterminate?  It is a fundamental step in the proof of a famous theorem of Weierstrass that a non-rational meromorphic function which admits an algebraic addition theorem is necessarily periodic.  The equation, due to A.R. Forsyth, is "solved" by him according to his following description: "Since the left-hand side is the sum of two functions of distinct and independent magnitudes, the form of the equation shows that it can be satisfied only if $x= 0$,so that..."

I am unable to follow this proof that necessarily $x=0$.  If one can show it, then it is easy to show that the only solution of the functional equation is $f(n)= a$ constant.

Comment: I don't understand what "x is an indeterminate" means here.  Are you saying that the displayed equation should hold for all integers $m, n,x$?  Or for all $m,n,x$ such that $m, n$ and $m+n+xmn$ are integers (with $x$ presumably rational)? Or are you saying something about an equality in some ring of functions?  (Of course it's possible some of these statements are equivalent, depending on the precise formulations.)

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: Looking at page 28 of arXiv:1212.6471 clarifies. Specifically, $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is some function and $x$ is some unknown integer such that the displayed equation holds for every $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Forsyth "concludes" that this is only possible for $x=0$. The OP wants to know if this conclusion is correct.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: Actually, a closer look at (3.9) in arXiv:1212.6471 suggests that $x$ in Forsyth's argument is not an integer but some unknown function $x=x(m,n)$. The OP should clarify indeed.

Comment: @GH from MO: thanks for doing the work of trying to figure out what this question means.  I'll note that if we were working with *positive* integers only, there'd be a counterexample to Forsyth's argument: take $x = 1$ and $f(n) = (\log(n + 1))/n$.  Here I'm interpreting the question as in your first comment.

Comment: @GHfromMO, good point! My answer below assumes $x$ is some fixed integer.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: You gave a nice argument. I arrived at the same conclusion (that $x=0$ when $x$ is an integer independent of $m$ and $n$), but my argument turned out to be wrong upon second look.

Comment: @TomLeinster: Thanks for your comment. My understanding, however, is that $f$ is integer valued.

Comment: @GHfromMO: thanks, quite right - that *is* clear in the question.  Nevertheless, Forsyth doesn't seem to invoke the integer-valuedness of $f$ in his argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\;g(n):=nf(n).\;$ If $x=0$ then the functional equation is $\;g(n)+g(m)=g(n+m)\;$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{Z},\;$ which is [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) for integers
and the general solution is $g(n)=cn$ which implies $\;c=f(n)\;$ for all $\;n\ne 0, n\in\mathbb{Z},\;$ while $f(0)$ is arbitrary.

Now assume $x\ne 0,\;\phi(n):=1+xn,\;h(\phi(n))=g(n),\;$ and let $n\oplus m:=n+m+xnm\;$ where $\phi(n\oplus m)=\phi(n)\phi(m).\;$ Then the functional equation is $\;g(n)+g(m)=g(n\oplus m)\;$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{Z},\;$ but now rewriting it as
 $\; h(\phi(n))+h(\phi(m))=h(\phi(n)\phi(m))\;$ leads to $\;k\:h(\phi(n))=h(\phi(n)^k)\;$ for all $k,n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\;$ with $k>0$.

Given $n\ne0,\;$let $\;t:=(\phi(n)^k-1)/x.\;$ Now $\;g((n-1)/x)=h(n),\;$ thus $\;k\:n\:f(n)=t\:f(t).$ Now, assuming that $\;|f(t)|\ge b>0\;$ for $k$ big enough, then the right side grows exponentially and the left linearly which is a contradiction. Thus eventually $f(t)=0$ and hence $f(n)=0.$ Note that $|f(t)|\ge b\;$ is implied by $f(t)$ being a nonzero integer.

My proof is very similar to the one in the other answer, but has a few more details. I think Forsyth's remark may be similar to the one in that too narrow margin of Fermat.

Added note: I implicitly define $h$ by $h(n)=g((n-1)/x)$ **only** for $n=1\pmod{x}$ and this is equivalent to $h(\phi(n))=g(n).$

Comment: What is $h$ in your second paragraph?  It looks like you're defining $g$, but the rest of your exposition suggests you still want $g : n \mapsto n f(n)$.  Are you defining $h$ by the equation $g(n) = h(\phi(n))$?  If so, then is the idea that $h$ is defined arbitrarily on numbers that aren't $1$ modulo $x$?  (In the same vein, what does $g((n - 1)/x)$ mean when $n \not\equiv 1 \pmod x$?)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps Forsyth meant the remark as a sort of heuristic. The paper linked in the comments by GH from MO mentions that his book is non-rigorous and has been criticized for this.

Nevertheless, we can give a rigorous proof that *pretty much* follows Forsyth's description. Suppose that there is such a function $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ and $x\neq 0$. Let $a> 1$ be some integer that is $1\pmod x$. Then our functional equation gives us for any natural $u,v$.
$$\frac{a^u-1}{x}f\left(\frac{a^u-1}{x}\right)+\frac{a^v-1}{x}f\left(\frac{a^v-1}{x}\right)=\frac{a^{u+v}-1}{x}f\left(\frac{a^{u+v}-1}{x}\right)$$
which in particular shows that the left hand side only depends on $u+v$. This means that there are integers $b,c$ such that
$$\frac{a^u-1}{x}f\left(\frac{a^u-1}{x}\right)=b+cu$$
and so for any large enough $u$ we must have $f\left(\frac{a^u-1}{x}\right)=b+cu=0$ since otherwise the left side is much larger in magnitude than the right side. This in turn means that $f\left(\frac{a^u-1}{x}\right)=0$ for any $u$. To conclude notice that for any $m\neq 0$
$$f(m)=f\left(\frac{(mx+1)^1-1}{x}\right)=0$$
and of course, $f(0)$ can be arbitrary.

**Side remark:** As a minor correction, the solution when $x=0$ is $f(m)=\text{constant}$ for all nonzero $m$ and an arbitrary value for $f(0)$, since our equation does not give any information about $f(0)$.